# ¿Cómo puedo comparar dos variables en prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

estoy haciendo un programa en prolog para comparar si dos numeros son cero, son positivos, etc. Al compilarlo me arroja: Warning:Singleton variables: [Numero1,Numero2], y también ERROR: Syntax error: Unbalanced operator.

Soy muy nuevo en prolog, he estado buscando soluciones pero la verdad no he podido comprender de donde vienen estos errores y como solucionarlos, este es mi codigo:

```
numeros:- write("Escribe un numero: "), nl, 
                           read(Numero1),
                           write("Escribe otro numero: "), nl,
                           read(Numero2).
          

cero(Numero1,Numero2):- (Numero1=:=0, Numero2=:=0)-> write("Ambos numeros son 0"), nl,.
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: en vez de -> ponle una coma, prolog no tiene lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

El warning de *singleton* te lo da el procedimiento `numeros/0` porque solamente aparece una vez cada una de las variables del warning (`Numero1` y `Numero2`).

Tal vez lo que quieras es agregar como parámetros esos números al procedimiento:

```
numeros(Numero1, Numero2):-
 writeln("Escribe un numero: "), 
 read(Numero1),
 writeln("Escribe otro numero: "),
 read(Numero2).
```

Luego tu segundo error no es por usar el operador [`->/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2), sino porque al final del procedimiento dejaste una `,`.

Si lo que quieres es que cuando ambos parámetros sean 0 entonces imprimir el mensaje, no instanciar variables y además que el procedimiento en sí siempre suceda (no falle) puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
cero(Numero1, Numero2) :-
    (   Numero1=:=0,
        Numero2=:=0
    ->  writeln("Ambos numeros son 0")
    ;   true
    ).
```

Caso de prueba:

```
?- numeros(A, B), cero(A, B).
Escribe un numero: 
|: 0.
Escribe otro numero: 
|: 0.
Ambos numeros son 0
A = B, B = 0.

?- numeros(A, B), cero(A, B).
Escribe un numero: 
|: 1.
Escribe otro numero: 
|: 0.

A = 1,
B = 0.
```

y si quieres que el procedimiento falle cuando algún parámetro no es 0, escribirías:

```
cero(Numero1,Numero2):-
  Numero1 =:= 0,
  Numero2 =:= 0,
  writeln("Ambos numeros son 0").
```